# EE1 to EE2 error on 2.1.4

Tags: ee1, upgrade, ee2-upgrades

did everything as described in the docs on upgrading EE1 to EE2 and getting stuck around 2.1.4 and then this error comes up on the screen.  How do I upgrade to 2.6.1 from 1.7.3 without getting this error?

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`wm_name` varchar(80), `wm_type` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'text', `wm_image_path` v' at line 3

ALTER TABLE `exp_member_groups` ADD `wm_id` int(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, `wm_name` varchar(80), `wm_type` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'text', `wm_image_path` varchar(100), `wm_test_image_path` varchar(100), `wm_use_font` char(1) DEFAULT 'y', `wm_font` varchar(30), `wm_font_size` int(3) UNSIGNED, `wm_text` varchar(100), `wm_vrt_alignment` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'top', `wm_hor_alignment` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'left', `wm_padding` int(3) UNSIGNED, `wm_opacity` int(3) UNSIGNED, `wm_x_offset` int(4) UNSIGNED, `wm_y_offset` int(4) UNSIGNED, `wm_x_transp` int(4), `wm_y_transp` int(4), `wm_font_color` varchar(7), `wm_use_drop_shadow` char(1) DEFAULT 'y', `wm_shadow_distance` int(3) UNSIGNED, `wm_shadow_color` varchar(7), `id` int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, `upload_location_id` int(4) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0', `title` varchar(255), `short_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT '', `resize_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT '', `width` int(10) DEFAULT '0', `height` int(10) DEFAULT '0', `watermark_id` int(4) UNSIGNED, `file_id` int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, `cat_id` int(10) UNSIGNED, `sort` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0', `is_cover` char(1) DEFAULT 'n', `site_id` int(4) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '1', `rel_path` varchar(255), `status` char(1) DEFAULT 'o', `mime_type` varchar(255), `file_name` varchar(255), `file_size` int(10) DEFAULT '0', `field_1` text, `field_1_fmt` tinytext, `field_2` text, `field_2_fmt` tinytext, `field_3` text, `field_3_fmt` tinytext, `field_4` text, `field_4_fmt` tinytext, `field_5` text, `field_5_fmt` tinytext, `field_6` text, `field_6_fmt` tinytext, `metadata` mediumtext NULL, `uploaded_by_member_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0', `upload_date` int(10), `modified_by_member_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0', `modified_date` int(10), `file_hw_original` varchar(20), `can_admin_upload_prefs` CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'n' NOT NULL AFTER `can_admin_channels`

Filename: /home/user/admin/expressionengine/libraries/Smartforge.php

Line Number: 122
```

So I then remove all the new EE2 files and try and go back to EE1, I load my homepage and get this error:

```
Site Error: Unable to Load Site Preferences; Invalid Preference Data
```

Answer (score 1):

Are the columns the script is trying to add to exp_member_groups already present, perhaps from an earlier aborted attempt at an upgrade?

Looks like that was the issue when someone posted [a similar question on EllisLab forum](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/236878/).

You mentioned that you restored the files, but did you restore the database as well?

Comment: yes sounds like a similar issue.  Wasn't worth the headache so I sinstalled a new install of 2.6.1 and manually created everythins